# How to balance load of HBase while loading file?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am new to Apache-Hadoop. I have Apache-Hadoop cluster of 3 nodes. I am trying to load a file having 4.5 billion records,but its not getting distributed to all nodes. The behavior is kind of region hotspotting.

I have removed "**hbase.hregion.max.filesize**" parameter from hbase-site.xml config file.

I observed that if I use 4 node's cluster then it distributes data to 3 nodes and if I use 3 node's cluster then it distributes to 2 nodes.

I think, I am missing some configuration.

Comment: May be your keys are not evenly balanced. Can you check the .META. table to see which region is not getting populated and it's start-key and end-key..

Comment: Thanks Chandra kant, 
One of node was missing in .META table. We cleared/formated the cluster and started again. Now its working well..!

Comment: Can I make it an answer then? You can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly with HBase the main issue is to prepare rowkeys that are not monotonically.
If they are, only oneregion server is used at the time:
http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/

This is HBase Reference Guide about RowKey Design:
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.design

And one more really good article:
http://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hbase-region-splitting-and-merging/

In our case predefinition of Region servers also improved the loading time:

```
create 'Some_table', { NAME => 'fam'}, {SPLITS=> ['a','d','f','j','m','o','r','t','z']}
```

Regards
Pawel